# Angular2 component property variable loses value after Init()

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Can someone explain what am I missing - I am assigning value to property variable in the OnInit lifecycle hook, but the value disappears when trying to access it again on click event:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-test',
    template: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getSearchResults()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Venues
        </button>`
})

export class SimpleTestComponent implements OnInit {
    public userLoc: string;
    constructor() { }
    getSearchResults(){
        console.log('userLoc: ' + this.userLoc);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initGeoLocation();
    }

    initGeoLocation() {
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                this.userLoc = `${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}`;
                console.log('userLoc: ' + this.userLoc);
            });
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are loosing correct context inside of getCurrentPosition callback function. Use arrow function instead:

```javascript
initGeoLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            this.userLoc = `${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}`;
            console.log('userLoc: ' + this.userLoc);
        });
    } 
}
```

Second potential problem. You need to be aware that geolocation API is asynchronous, so the value for `userLoc` might be unavailable if you click *too soon*. Consider disabling button until current location is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

here is working plnkr for your question:

http://plnkr.co/edit/uG4rfXySQYWHzlj6iIuj?p=preview

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="initGeoLocation()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Venues
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even though it didnt solve the problem - it shows the need for adding unit tests as you have done, and which I will try to integrate now.

I wouldn't separate template into templateUrl file as in plunker for simple file, as per [Angular2 style guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide) :

_Keep the components' templates as lean as possible and inline them inside of the @Component decorator.

Extract the more complex and bigger templates, longer than 15 lines of code, into a separate file and put them next to their controllers' definition._

Comment: ohh thanks for posting such a great link i.e `style guide` for angular2.